# I can't refresh my screen with opengl

Tags: android, opengl-es, updates, runnable

I try to learn opengl but I have some problem because it s difficult to find information on it.

I can create a form on my screen but I can't update the screen, and I try a lot of thing.

Here I use runnable but nothing work.

Thanks for your help, here is my code for the surfaceView

```
public class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView implements Runnable{
int x1=1440,y1=2560,pub,i=1;

private final MyGLRenderer mRenderer;

public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context) {
    super(context);


    // Create an OpenGL ES 2.0 context.
    setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
    //fix for error No Config chosen, but I don't know what this does.
    super.setEGLConfigChooser(8 , 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
    // Set the Renderer for drawing on the GLSurfaceView
    mRenderer = new MyGLRenderer();
    setRenderer(mRenderer);

    // Render the view only when there is a change in the drawing data
    setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
}

private final float TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR = 180.0f / 320;
private float mPreviousX;
private float mPreviousY;
public void modif(){
    requestRender();
    try{Thread.sleep(20);}
    catch(Exception e){}}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    // MotionEvent reports input details from the touch screen
    // and other input controls. In this case, you are only
    // interested in events where the touch position changed.

    float x = e.getX();
    float y = e.getY();

    switch (e.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            float dx = x - mPreviousX;
            float dy = y - mPreviousY;

            // reverse direction of rotation above the mid-line
            if (y > getHeight() / 2) {
                dx = dx * -1 ;
            }

            // reverse direction of rotation to left of the mid-line
            if (x < getWidth() / 2) {
                dy = dy * -1 ;
            }

            mRenderer.setAngle(
                    mRenderer.getAngle() +
                            ((dx + dy) * TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR));  // = 180.0f / 320
            requestRender();

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            modif();

    }

    mPreviousX = x;
    mPreviousY = y;
    return true;
}

public void run(){
    while(true){
        modif();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Does your view update when you touch/swipe it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are using the tutorial from the Android doc, right ?

https://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/touch.html#angle

In order to move the shape, you have to move your finger while touching the screen.

Are you trying to accomplish something else ?

Comment: You right, but i had something in ondrawfram fonction in MyGlRender class for see a difference.                                                             
        if(i<-1.0f){i=1.0f;}
        else{i-=0.1f;}
        mSquare.draw(scratch,i,0.8f);                                                            i permit to transform the square but the form doesn't evolve. The square only move and be transform when i touch the screen

Comment: Is the "modif" in your while loop ever called ?

Comment: Not sure if a runnable GLSurfaceView is the way to go. I don't know where you call run() on your runnable GLSurfaceView, but I hope it's not on the main thread. A while(true) on the UI thread is not a good idea.

Comment: I try different loop in every location possible but it doesn't work, when i put a loop the screen is white without the square.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution when i readed again the tuto, i put the line `setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
I delete the line and now the cpde working.`